# Stripe API - Filter Subscriptions by Coupon Id. (Python)

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to access some Stripe subscriptions, but only those with a certain coupon. To obtain the subscriptions, I'm currently using:

```
resource_list = getattr(stripe, 'Subscriptions').list(limit=100,
                                             created={"gte": start_date, "lt": end_date},
                                             **kwargs)
```

I've attempted expanding the discount field by passing in `expand = ['data.discount']` as a kwarg, but I'd like to find a way to actually filter by the coupon id in the call itself - that way I don't have to obtain all of my subscriptions when I don't need them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to filter by `data.discount` in the call itself. It sounds like your implementation is the best way (currently) to delineate subscriptions by their corresponding coupon/discount.

Depending on how important this is, you could alternatively modify your integration to create a `metadata` key-value pair with the ID of the Coupon, so that you could use the [Subscription Search API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/search) to search for (and return) only the subscriptions that have `metadata['coupon']:'some_coupon_id'`.